# SQL `LIKE` complexity

Tags: sql, database, complexity-theory, sql-like

Does anyone know what the complexity is for the SQL `LIKE` operator for the most popular databases?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "complexity".

Comment: I'm sorry, I was asking this for a friend, he meant in big O, but that's all I know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's consider the three core cases separately. This discussion is MySQL-specific, but might also apply to other DBMS due to the fact that indexes are typically implemented in a similar manner.

**`LIKE 'foo%'` is quick if run on an indexed column.** MySQL indexes are a variation of B-trees, so when performing this query it can simply descend the tree to the node corresponding to `foo`, or the first node with that prefix, and traverse the tree forward. All of this is very efficient.

**`LIKE '%foo'` can't be accelerated by indexes and will result in a full table scan.** If you have other criterias that can by executed using indices, it will only scan the the rows that remain after the initial filtering.

*There's a trick though*: If you need to do suffix matching - searching for file names with extension `.foo`, for instance - you can achieve the same performance by adding a column with the same contents as the original one but with the characters in reverse order.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN col_reverse VARCHAR (256) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX idx_col_reverse (col_reverse);
UPDATE my_table SET col_reverse = REVERSE(col);
```

Searching for rows with `col` ending in `.foo` then becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE col_reverse LIKE 'oof.%'
```

**Finally, there's `LIKE '%foo%'`, for which there are no shortcuts.** If there are no other limiting criterias which reduces the amount of rows to a feasible number, it'll cause a hard performance hit. You might want to consider a full text search solution instead, or some other specialized solution.

Comment: Don't you mean 
   AND col_reverse like 'oof%'
?

Comment: Don't you need 'oof%' on col_reverse?  Also, the second query fragment answers a different question from the first.

Comment: "col LIKE '%foo%'" will match occurrences of "foo" anywhere in the field. "col LIKE 'foo%' OR col_reverse LIKE 'oof%'" will only match a subset of those results (ie, where the field begins or ends with "foo").

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the RDBMS, the data (and possibly size of data), indexes and how the LIKE is used (with or without prefix wildcard)!

You are asking too general a question.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but it's a question for a friend, and he didn't tell me more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the performance impact:

The problem of like is that it keeps the database from using an index. On Oracle I think it doesn't use indexes anymore (but I'm still on Oracle 9). SqlServer uses indexes if the wildcard is only at the end. I don't know about other databases.

Comment: Prevent random access on an index, but surely not scanning of an index (although it might change which indexes it uses)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Scanning the whole index (and joining to the table afterwards) isn't faster then scanning the real table, is it?

Comment: Scanning the whole index and joining to the table afterwards can be MUCH faster than scanning the real table.  Indexes are typically narrower than tables and more "records" fit on a database page.